# passing a get parameter in django named variable

Tags: django, django-urls

My url patterns is as defined in django -

```
url(r'^import-contacts$', 'import_contacts', name='import_contacts'),
```

The view expects a get parameter, which I parse in the view and process it, the url should be of the format - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/import-contact/?service=google`

In the template I do the following -

```
<a href="{% url "import_contacts" %}"> Text Here </a>
```

This will generate  the following url - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/import-contact/` and not the url which is reqd.

Any idea on how to pass get variables with the named url params.

Comment: Django would only generate the URL for you, not the `GET` parameters - You would have to do that explicitly yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it after the tag:

```
<a href="{% url "import_contacts" %}?service=google">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url patterns should be like this:

```
url(r'^import-contacts/?service=(?P<service>\w+)/$', 'import_contacts', name='import_contacts'),
```

The view should be like this:

```
def import_contacts(request, service):
    # Do something with get variable "service"
```

Now, if you simply use

```
<a href="{% url "import-contacts" %}">TEXT HERE</a>
```

it will get you to url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/import-contacts/?service=`

You need to explicitly give GET parameter. Either hardcode it or using templates.